# Scale text inputs for iphone 4s- iphone 6s plus

Tags: ios, layout

How to make components responsive. I want to scale my text inputs and one lable to be always in center and to be scaled. I'm new to this.

xcode deisgner 
[image: xcode deisgner]

iphone 6s plus 
[image: iPhone 6s plus]

iphone 4s 
[image: iphone 4s]

Comment: How about you show a little reseach and tell why you cannot use auto layout, why you would like to override the user's settings (violating apples HIG) and at least read the mouse overs on the tags you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the Main.storyboard, select the items you want to center and select "Add new allignment constraints" and add Horizontally/Vertically in Container.

[image]

That way the elements will be centered on all devices.

For Scale use "Add new Constraint" and select "Height/Width". That the size is the same on all devices.

[image]

Comment: That was a surprise to get the answer accepted 2 years later :D

Comment: Better late than never I guess